# Multirow subselect as parameter to `execute using`

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, dynamicquery

The multirow subselect will be used in the right hand side of the `in` operator in the `where` clause:

```
create table t (a integer);
insert into t (a) values (1), (9);

drop function if exists f();

create function f()
returns void as $$
begin
execute '
    select a
    from t
    where a in $1
' using (select 1 union select 2);
end;$$
language plpgsql;

select f();

ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (select 1 union select 2)"
PL/pgSQL function "f" line 3 at EXECUTE statement
```

How to achieve what the above function would if it worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see nothing in your question that couldn't more easily be solved with:

```
SELECT a
FROM   t
JOIN  (VALUES (1), (2)) x(a) USING (a); -- any query returning multiple int
```

Can you clarify the necessity in your example?

---

As a proof of concept, this would be simpler / faster:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.f1()
  RETURNS SETOF integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
    SELECT a
    FROM t
    WHERE a = ANY($1)'
USING ARRAY(VALUES (1), (2)); -- any query here
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

#### Performance of IN () and = ANY()

Your observation is spot on. And there is reason for it. Try:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

The query plan will reveal:

> Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))

PostgreSQL transforms the `id IN (..)` construct into `id = ANY(..)` internally. These two perform identically - except for a negligible overhead penalty.

My code is only faster in building the statement - exactly as you diagnosed.

Comment: Yes simpler and probably faster at building the query (I'm accepting it) but the execution plan cost is exactly the same as my own answer (`=any` vs `in`). The necessity is that the table is partitioned and if the `where` parameters are not constants the planner will not optimize the query.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: I added a bit concerning your observation about performance.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: You could take something like my simple query and run it with `EXECUTE`. Forces re-planning in any case. A `JOIN` will be faster than an `IN ()` expression, especially with longer lists of values.

Comment: No I mean what I wrote. Check [one of the last paragraphs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CAVEATS) _http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CAVEATS_ I have experienced sluggish queries turn into blazing fast ones when the `where` or `join` parameters were turned into constants. Oh you just deleted your comment. I guess you checked the manual or something. No re-planning will avoid this planner behavior when the condition involves a partitioned table.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: Yeah, I removed the first sentence, right after I had typed it because I had it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
create function f()
returns setof integer as $$
begin
return query execute format('
    select a
    from t
    where a in %s
', replace(replace(array(select 1 union select 2)::text, '{', '('), '}', ')'));
end$$
language plpgsql;
```