# array_length() and cardinality() of an empty array return one of array size

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like :

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id bigint not null,
    available_region_code character varying(255)[],
    is_valid bigint,
)
```

I want use`array_length()`, `cardinality()` or `available_region_code ='{}'` to select empty `available_region_code`  columns but it failed, the length return one.

[image]

Why does this happen and how to solve this problem.

Comment: I would say you have an array with one string in it, and that string consists only of non-printing characters.  Or at least, the unstated client you are using considers them non-printing.

Comment: What do you get for `available_region_code[1] IS NULL`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `available_region_code[1] IS NULL` is Fase, maybe like @jjanes says, there are non-printing characters in the array.

Comment: To see details, you could examine `available_region_code[1]::bytea`. That will show you the bytes stored.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what reason causes this problem. Maybe like jjanes say in the comments the array has a non-printing character.

In the last, I use `(CAST(ARRAY_TO_JSON(available_region_code) AS VARCHAR) IN ('[null]', '[""]'))` to check empty array which learn from answer of Zone in question([How to check if an array is empty in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155666/how-to-check-if-an-array-is-empty-in-postgres)).

The result on blow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for a similar issue I had in presto based SQL, I created a case statement like:

**case when available_region_code[1] = '' then 0 else cardinality(available_region_code) end as cardinality**

Not sure if this helps in your use case, but it resulted in 0's for my empty arrays, and the correct counts for all others.